# How can i create common log in for admin and user?

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication, mysqli

I have two table namely **ADMIN** and **USER** how can i build common log in form using php?
i want only two field in that form.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: add a dropdown or something which can tell it is user login or admin..manage roles, use 1 for users and 2 for admins..

Comment: what you have tried so far this question should be closed without doing any effort and getting complete result is v bad for  learning purpose

Answer (score 3):

set a usertype field in table **users** like,

**usertype = 1** corresponds to admin and **usertype = 0** corresponds to user.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally You should have one table called user and then another table called user_role that will contain user role that is either a normal user or an admin.
In your case set another column.

Let's say:

```
user_type ='1';
```

or

```
user_type ='0';
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be beneficial for the database and script if it was a 1/0 to represent true/false?

Comment: Point I corrected @DarylGill

Comment: @DarylGill, at this point you can define the level of access a user can have.

Comment: Very true, did not think I would touch that, but yeah for the OPS reference. It's easier matching up a number from a database to set permissions than it is working with the strings from the database, Thats my preference integer over string though. Other developers might have a different scenario. But as ulfric said. This can offer future expansion with user access; instead of having to heavily modify inputs/reads from the DB

Comment: On the other hand, base on my experience being an `admin` and other `user role` can have different definitions. On my system, a user can have a `role` and also a `flag` for being an admin. Then on the `role` table I can even define the `data` (specific database tables) and `object` (e.g. buttons) access for the system.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using some kind of permission levels, you could have a users table with all the stuff about all users, then a user_admin table with a same primary key (username) containing all the permission stuff.

You could perform a JOIN on both tables selecting `username`, `password` and `salt`, but you'd have to stop the same username being put in both.

Comment: Hi, please use comments to ask for clarification on the question, rather than asking them in your answer itself (otherwise it risk being deleted for not being an answer).

Comment: Thanks Matt, I wasn't sure whether to make it a comment or an answer since it kind of contained both. I guess 'both' was the right answer. :)